# A bus carries $67$ travelers of three types

Tags: systems-of-equations, word-problem

> A bus carries $67$ travelers of three types:
>
> - travelers who pay the entire ticket, which costs $\$3200$.
> - students who have a $43$% discount.
> - local retirees who only pay $23$% of the ticket price.
>
> The bus collection on that trip was $\$6,292,000$. Calculate the number of travelers in each class knowing that the number of retirees was the same as the number of other travelers.

Solution:

- $x$: travelers who pay the entire ticket, $\$3200$
- $y$: students who have a $43\%$ discount, that is, they pay the $57\%$ of the total ticket. ($3200*57\%=1824$)
- $z$: local retirees who only pay $23$% of the ticket price. ($3200*23\%=736$)

The equations are

$$\begin{aligned}
x + y +z &= 67 \\
100x + 57y +23z &= 196625 \\
x+y-z &= 0
\nonumber
\end{aligned}$$

The solutions are $x =  \frac{193945}{43}$, $y = -\frac{385009}{86} $ and $z = 33.5$. However, $y$ is negative. If they ask about the number of travelers, what does it tell me in the result?

---

equations:
*1)* $x+y+z=0$

*2)* $3200x+1824y+736z=6292000$

*3)* $z=x+y$

Comment: Even $z = 33.5$ doesn't make sense, which you can find by just the first and third equations

Comment: Your solution is correct.  The problem is wrong.

Comment: If every pasenger pay the full price, the total would be $67 \times 3200=214400$ which is much less than $6292000$

Comment: Any odd number of travelers doesn't make sense (or number of retirees was the same as the number of other travelers isn't right). Are you sure it was $67$?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the exercise data are correct

Comment: @saulspatz. Could you find positive integer values for $n$, $s$, $r$ in my answer for, say, $P < 100$ being even and $T<3200P$. I am very bad with this kind of problems (as well as with many other). Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote *"Yes, I am sure that the exercise data are correct"* but it cannot be.

Let $n$ be the number of "normal" travelers, $s$ the number of students and $r$ the number of retirees and put numbers to have
$$ 3200 n+1824 s+736 r=T\tag 1$$
$$n+s+r=P\tag 2$$
$$r=n+s\tag 3$$ where $T$ is the bus collection and $P$ the number of passengers.

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$ makes $r=\frac P 2$ so $P$ cannot be odd.

Second remark : if everyone pays the full price, it would be $3200P$ and $67\times 3200=214400$ which does not have anything to do with the $6292000$ given. To get such a collection, the bus would be bigger than a train !

Just solving the three equations would give
$$n=\frac{T-1280 P}{1376}\qquad s=\frac{1968P-T}{1376}\qquad r=\frac P2$$ and each of $n,s,r$ must be an integer (again with $T \leq 3200 P$).

Answer (score 3):

Following [Claude Leibovici's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/) answer,
we have $$s-n=\frac{3248r - T}{688}.$$
Noting that $32\mid T,$ let $T=32k,$ then 
$$s-n=\frac{203r - 2k}{43}.$$

If we set $T=6292000$ as in the original problem, then $k = 196625.$
[Integer solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solutions+for+(3248+r+-+6292000)%2F688+%3D+q)
occur for $r = 43m + 1966$ and $s-n = 203m + 136$
where $m$ is an integer. 
But we also have $s+n=r,$
so $$s = \tfrac12(r + (s-n)) = 123 m + 1051$$
and $$n = \tfrac12(r - (s-n)) = 915 - 80 m = 5 (183 - 16 m).$$

Since $n$ and $s$ must be non-negative, this limits the possible solutions to
$-8\leq m \leq 11.$
Hence the minimum number of retirees occurs when $m = -8$ and 
$r = 43(-8)+1966 = 1622.$
There are then $67$ students and $1555$ other passengers.

The problem is therefore solvable if $67$ is the number of *students*
rather than the total number of passengers.

Comment: Perhaps a cruise ship rather than a bus?  This makes both the number of passengers  and the fare more reasonable.  But this is a new kind of puzzle: find the typo in this math exercise.

Comment: @saulspatz. Then, many puzzles ! Seriously, I wonder how so many typo's can happen.

Comment: $\frac{6292000}{3200} = 1966.25$ The $0.25$ is important. Then, at least $1966.25$ passengers.